# jQuery filter table with multi select

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I'm trying to filter a table with some filters. Some are simple selects, and others are multiples. For the simple ones, that's ok, but not the multiple.

I want to follow this logic :

1. Passing through the array which contains the filter (`filtre_transports`)
2. Passing through the array which contains the value(s) (`ligne_transports`)
3. If an element of the *1.* isn't in the *2.* so not display the line (`transports_matches = false`)

I made this code :

```
// Pass through each line of the table
jQuery('#agents_liste tbody tr').not('.vide').each(function() {
    var transports_matches = true;

    // ligne_transports is an array contains values to compare with the filter
    var ligne_transports = jQuery(this).children('td').eq(2).text().split('###');

    // filtre_transports is an array contains the selected val of a multi select
    jQuery(filtre_transports).each(function() {
        var filtre = jQuery(this);
        var filtreOk = false;

        jQuery(ligne_transports).each(function() {
            if (filtre == jQuery(this)) {
                filtreOk = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (!filtreOk) {
            transports_matches = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The problem : When we have filters selected, the result `transports_matches` is always false.

Btw, I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957491/using-jquery-to-filter-a-table-from-multiple-select-elements) where the answer is to use classes, but is there a way without them ?

EDIT : You can see the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r4mfv/1/).

Thanks

Comment: Using classes is most definitely not required. Can you post it on jsfiddle so we can have a look at a (not) working example?

Comment: You can now see the JSFiddle, thanks for the comment anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/r4mfv/2/

You had a couple of issues:

1. `$(filtre_transports).each` is not the way to iterate over an array, you should use `$.each(filtre_transports, function() {...})`.
2. You should cast `filtre` and `this` to `String` before comparing them.

Comment: You sure that a simple $(x).each() is not good to iterate over an array ? If you have a link that speaking about it, please post it in comment, I'm interested in it.. And thanks a lot for your answer, +1 and "accepted" ! :)

Comment: $(x).each is used to iterate over a jQuery object, $.each - over any iterable JS object. [docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)